# Resize DIV when content is repositioned

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

So, the question is it possible to self-adjust the size of a DIV when its content is re-positioned?

Let me explain myself better:

I have a container `div` which has another `div` inside. This last one can receive additional components via `jQuery.append()` method.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
<div id="content"></div>

<div id="another">Hello World</div>
```

**JS**

```
var a = $("#another");
$("#content").append(a);
```

So far so good, however, when I try to resize `div#another`, `div#content` does not change its size and `div#another` is going to fly.

```
$("#another").position({left:100, top:100});
```

Comment: Is #another relatively or absolutely positioned in your CSS? "Elements that are positioned relatively are still considered to be in the normal flow of elements in the document. In contrast, an element that is positioned absolutely is taken out of the flow and thus takes up no space when placing other elements. The absolutely positioned element is positioned relative to nearest positioned ancestor. If a positioned ancestor doesn't exist, the initial container is used." (from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/position)

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are appending the child element, add or remove css class to the parent element like:

```
var a = $ ("#another");
var content = $ ("#content")
content.append(a);
```

`condition>> ? content.addClass('scenario1') : content.addClass('scenario2')`

then add necessary style to scenario1 and scenario2 like:

```
.scenario1 {
   left: 100;
   top: 100
}

.scenario2 {
   left: 50;
   top: 50
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var a = $ ("#another");
 $ ("#content").append(a).css('width',<new value>);
```

After appending, resize the width of parent div to required values.